# PowerPivot Memory error

Tags: excel, memory, out-of-memory, powerpivot

I'm running 32-bit Excel 2010 with the PowerPivot v11.0.3129.0 add-on. My laptop is running 64-bit Windows 7 with 8 GB RAM and an Intel i5 processor. I am trying to import a table from an Access DB. It has 1,400,054 rows and 80 columns. When I attempt to import it I get this error: **The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application**. I can bring in all of the data if I split it up and import it as several separate tables. Is there a way to append the table splits together after they are loaded in the PowerPivot environment?

I checked my RAM while trying to import. The RAM allocated to Excel never exceeds 700MB. My total RAM never exceeds 4GB. I have 300+ GB of space on my computer. When I succesfully import the data as several smaller tables, the total excel file size is less than 50 MB.

I

I can not make any software changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to switch to the latest builds of Excel 2013 or 2016 (which handle [LAA](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/excel-memory-checking-tool-using-laa-to-increase-useable-excel-memory/)) if you have to keep to 32-bit Excel, or switch to 64-bit Excel.

Note that Excel 2010 has a theoretical limit of 2 Gigabytes of Virtual memory, but in practice because of memory fragmentation etc it often runs out of memory at around half of that. Also Virtual Memory used tends to be higher than the memory reported by Task Manager.

Determining Excel's Virtual Memory usage is surprisingly difficult (its not shown by Task Manager): the best way is to download Process Explorer and add the column for Virtual Memory.

Or you may find this little [tool I built](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/excel-memory-checking-tool-using-laa-to-increase-useable-excel-memory/) is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I'm unable to change software, because I am on a laptop provided by my employer.

So you think I'm still reaching Excel's RAM limitations even though I am well under half of the limit?

Comment: memory usage is a very technical subject: virtual memory is not the same thing as the private working set memory shown by Task Manager. But probably you hve run out of virtual memory. If you want to find out how much virtual memory you are using then download Process Explorer from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx